# Induced map on spectrum of the rings on integral extensions

Tags: commutative-algebra

I know that if  $A$ is contained in $B$ and $B$ is an integral extension of $A$, then the induced map on spectrum of the rings is surjective (and closed). Is it true if $B$ is not assumed to be integral over $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take any domain $R$ that is not a field, and consider the inclusion $R \hookrightarrow Q$, where $Q$ is the field of fractions of $R$. Then $|\text{Spec}(R)| > 1$, but $|\text{Spec}(Q)| = 1$, so $\text{Spec}(Q) \to \text{Spec}(R)$ cannot be surjective (and as Georges Elencwajg points out, it is not closed either).

Comment: ....nor closed.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Thank you for pointing that out - it is just as clearly not closed either!